# How to lazy load error route with child route in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/GyUApIPQzTvp9vIahYdT?p=preview

I have routes setup like this in `app.module`:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DummyComponent
  },

  {
    path: '', // is this right?
    component: SingleComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '**', // is this right?
        loadChildren: 'src/lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

And on `lazy.module` I have

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '**', // is this right?
    component: LazyComponent
  }
];
```

The problem is that `SingleComponent` (the page template) is actually loading, but the page content (`LazyComponent`) is not loading. (Click `notfound` link to see the result in Plunker)

How should I configure this so `SingleComponent` (the template) and `LazyComponent` (the content) load showing the page correctly?

Note: This `LazyComponent` is supposed to be an error page, so I want to catch all routes (`/notfound`, `/invalid-url`, `/<anything that doesn't exist in router>`)

Comment: You should add your `path: '**'` route bound to your error component at the top level of your application, as last route. It means that if nothing is found before this matcher, you'll get this route (which is what you want for a not found page).

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing here is calling the /dummy and /notfound routes.

```
<a routerLink="/dummy">dummy</a>
<a routerLink="/notfound">notfound</a>
```

And in your routes definition you haven't defined those routes. What you might want to do is:

```
const routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dummy', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'dummy',
    component: DummyComponent
  },

  {
    path: 'notfound',
    component: SingleComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: 'src/lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

The first line will redirect to the dummy route if you leave an empty route. What you also don't need is the ** wildcard in this specific case.

I hope this helps and that I have understood your problem.

Comment: Well, that works, but this `notfound` is just an example of a route that doesn't exist. I want to render this lazy component in case the user goes to a page that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this, the downside is that it changes the URL:

App routes:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DummyComponent
  },

  {
    path: '',
    component: SingleComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'error',
        loadChildren: 'src/lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule'
      }
    ]
  },

  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'error' },
];
```

Lazy routes:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '**',
    component: LazyComponent
  }
];
```

Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/xktoV02EoGjPNwrW2VjR?p=preview